# Get a count of turtles with a combination of values

Tags: netlogo, agent-based-modeling

I am trying to count the number of "buyer" type turtles, which have a certain surplus (turtle variable) greater than or equal to zero, and price (another turtle variable) greater than the current turtle's price (already grabbed in local variable myprice...although there may be a more direct way to put it in)
`let countup count buyers with ([surplus >= 0] and [price > myprice])`
NetLogo returns

> Expected a TRUE/FALSE here, rather than a list or block.

`let countup count buyers with (surplus >= 0 and price > myprice)` returns

> WITH expected this input to be a TRUE/FALSE block, but got a TRUE/FALSE instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Close! You're looking for:

```
let countput count buyers with [ surplus >= 0 and price > myprice ]
```

`with` is a report that takes two arguments, like so

```
<turtleset> with <report block>
```

where the reporter block is a clump of code surrounded by `[ ]` that will result in either true or false. In general `[ ]` is netlogo's way of grouping together code so you can doing something special with it, such as having each agent in an agentset run it. Hope that helps!

Also, I assume you've got something like `let myprice price` on, say, the line above this one. You can combine those lines like so (not saying this code is the right way to do it, just wanted to show another option):

```
let countput count buyers with [ surplus >= 0 and price > [ price ] of myself ]
```

Checkout the docs for (the very poorly named) [`myself`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#myself).

Comment: Awesome! In fact, based on your advice, I was able to do a nested conditional `let countdown count buyers with [ (surplus < 0 and price > [ price ] of myself) or (price > [ price ] of myself)] `